# When I use jQueryMobile, scrolling has appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, scroll

I just make a example site because I want to make a mobile site..

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Mobile</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <link href="./framework/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="./framework/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./framework/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Button</h1>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="minus">button</a>
            </div>  
            <div data-role="content">   
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home">button</a> 
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right">button</a> <br/>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top">button</a> <br/>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="bottom">button</a> <br/>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">button</a> <br/>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="letter-s">button</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Copyright</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when it is started in Mobile, a scrollbar has appeared..
When I don't use jQueryMobile, the scrollbar has gone..
I'm curious why scrollbar is made..
Because of ajax-loader? or Because of jQuery-css setting?
The scrollbar just conduct 1mm scrolling.. I want to remove it

Sample site is http://mbtistudy.cafe24.com/jstest.html
I'll appreciate your help..

Comment: I don't see the scroll when resized smaller.

Comment: In web(chrome), i don't see scrollbar too.. but when it started in Mobile Phone(Android), scrollbar appears..

Comment: I think near by 350~400px height, mobile scrollbar appears, but my page is just 300px height... When started in more than 450px mobile circumstance, scrollbar doesn't exist..

Comment: You mean in height. I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: @C-link scrollbar just conduct 1mm scrolling.. I want to remove it

Comment: use jQM latest version 1.4

Comment: @Omar Oh my god.. ther version was the problem... thank you......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then you have to remove the min-height from `ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active` which is causing the scrollbar. Also remove min-height where ever it's found also to `.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page` if it's still showing then add `overflow: hidden` to this.

Comment: I removed min-height or changed property for 100%.(http://mbtistudy.cafe24.com/framework/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css) but scrollbar still appears... thank you

Comment: but I have removed min-height and set overflow: hidden; it's removing scrollbar.

Comment: The jQuery Version was the problem.. thank you for helping me. Use latest version..

Comment: and what if I want to show the content, not tu hide, but to resize ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales sorry, couldn't understand.

Comment: If I use hide, the content when overflow will hide, causing to hide some elements. What I want is that when the content is too large, then to resize all the content to fit the screen.

Comment: then you can use overflow: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Add following style class into your page it will remove scroll bar.

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page 
{
     min-height: 300px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: attach it, but it still exists... thanks...(http://mbtistudy.cafe24.com/framework/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css)

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your CSS this will probability help:

```
.ui-content .ui-listview, .ui-panel-inner>.ui-listview { margin:0em}
```